# Direct2D/SharpDX: Why is LinearGradientBrush's quality so low?

Tags: sharpdx, direct2d

I'm using Direct2D with SharpDX. I'm filling a rectangle with a `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
    renderTarget,
    new LinearGradientBrushProperties
    {
        StartPoint = bounds.ToRawVector2TopLeft(),
        EndPoint = bounds.ToRawVector2BottomLeft()
    },
    new GradientStopCollection(
        renderTarget,
        new[]
        {
            new GradientStop
            {
                Color = new RawColor4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f),
                Position = 0
            },
            new GradientStop
            {
                Color = new RawColor4(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f),
                Position = 1
            }
        }));
...
renderTarget.FillRectangle(bounds.ToRawRectangleF(), brush);
```

Unfortunately, the gradient quality is *terrible* (500x250 so StackOverflow doesn't shrink it):

[image: Direct2D LinearGradientBrush]

The problem is much more visible at larger render target sizes.

Same machine, here's Photoshop CC 2019 with the same stop colors (500x250 so StackOverflow doesn't shrink it):

[image: Photoshop CC 2019]

I zoomed way in on each screenshot and Direct2D's dithering algorithm seems to be terrible compared to Photoshop's. I realize that there simply aren't many colors available in this fine of a gradient, so I'm not asking for more colors but rather better dithering. Are there any settings I can use to improve the rendering quality of fine gradients like this in Direct2D?

I also read about `GradientStopCollection1`, which has a wrapper in SharpDX but doesn't appear to be usable anywhere. Would this solve my issue?

Comment: These gradients are not the same as can be easily check by inspecting upper and lower colors. Also PS might be performing color correction so you should disable it to make sure that it is using the same linear RGB mode.

Comment: In effect, yes, they might not be the same, but that was kind of the point of my post. I'm less concerned about why the Photoshop gradient is different than how to increase the quality of the Direct2D gradient. I'm guessing that I can't given the two color stops are so close together and there doesn't seem to be a way to adjust the dithering algorithm. Also, I promise I selected 10% and 20% for the two stops when I was drawing the gradient in Photoshop.